# Check if variables exist in a for loop in php

Tags: php

I need to check if a variable from the database exists in a `for` loop. I have tried but wasn't giving me expected result.

```
$idate = $row['joinDate'];//value from db
$yearOnly = date('Y', strtotime($idate));
```

```php
define('DOB_YEAR_START', 1900);
for ($count = $current_year; $count >= DOB_YEAR_START; $count--)
{
    if($yearOnly == $count){
        $selected = "selected";
    }
    print '<option value="'.$count.'" '.$selected.'>'.$count.'</option>';
}
```

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question. Can you elaborate, including the output you got vs the output you expected?

Comment: @DarraghEnright Please check updated question.

Comment: Where is the database query?

Comment: You need to have an `else` value for `$selected`, otherwise the previous value will remain for the following iteration (also, it may not be defined the first time and trigger a notice).

Answer (score 0):

To check the value you can use `isset()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or `empty()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) or even `array_key_exists()` (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

```
// isset method
if (isset($row['joinDate'])) {
    // handle when value is set
} else {
    // handle when value is not set
}
```

```
// empty method
if (empty($row['joinDate'])) {
    // handle when value is not empty
} else {
    // handle when value is empty
}
```

```
// array_key_exists method
if (array_key_exists('joinDate', $row)) {
    // handle when row has this element
} else {
    // handle when row does not have this element
}
```